# Rotating droplet of liquid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, rotational-dynamics

I'm interested in the fluid dynamics of a spherical droplet of liquid whose surface is forced to rotate at a constant velocity. I'm interested in either steady-state solutions (the internal flow patterns after forced surface rotation for a long time) or time-dependent solutions describing the response of the liquid to a step-function increase in rotation at its surface.

Has anyone seen this in the literature before?

Comment: Have you tried an internet search?  How about : https://physics.aps.org/articles/v1/38  or  http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/120/jres.120.007.pdf

Comment: What have you done to find such literature?  If you are in academia and your institution has a subscription, have you tried Web of Science http://wok.mimas.ac.uk/  or some other scientific literature database such as arXiv? https://arxiv.org/